# Reading data from Azure Blob Storage into Azure Databricks using /mnt/

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I've successfully mounted my blob storage to Databricks, and can see the defined mount point when running `dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/")`. This has `size=0` - it's not clear if this is expected or not.

When I try and run `dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/<mount-name>")`, I get this error:
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: / is not found`

When I try and write a simple file to my mounted blob with `dbutils.fs.put("/mnt/<mount-name>/1.txt", "Hello, World!", True)`, I get the following error (shortened for readability):

```
ExecutionError: An error occurred while calling z:com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.FSUtils.put. : shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original exception for details.
...
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The specified resource does not exist.
```

All the data is in the root of the Blob container, so I have not defined any folder structures in the `dbutils.fs.mount` code.

*thinking emoji*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here is making sure you are using the 'correct' part of your Shared Access Signature (SAS). When the SAS is generated, you'll find there are lots of different parts of it that you can use - it's likely sent to you as one long connection string, e.g:

```
BlobEndpoint=https://<storage-account>.blob.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://<storage-account>.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://<storage-account>.file.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://<storage-account>.table.core.windows.net/;SharedAccessSignature=sv=<date>&ss=nwrt&srt=sco&sp=rsdgrtp&se=<datetime>&st=<datetime>&spr=https&sig=<long-string>
```

When you define your mount point, use the value of the `SharedAccessSignature` key, e.g:

```
sv=<date>&ss=nwrt&srt=sco&sp=rsdgrtp&se=<datetime>&st=<datetime>&spr=https&sig=<long-string>
```

Comment: This also worked for me, I was using the connection string but switched to the SAS token and removed the `?` from the beginning